# iphone, How should I allow editing of a row item on a selection / search view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

[image]

I have a screen which allows users to add several categories at once. They can search all categories and select a category.  I also added a swiped right delete feature.

However, I'm really unsure how to allow rows items to be renamed / edited ?

At the moment the swipe delete isn't obvious and could be missed.

I'm short on real estate and I can't see how I would provide an edit / rename feature.

I know this question could be asked on the UI stack site. But I think this is more relevant to functionality and the framework that can be employed, designers won't know what functionality is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a:

```
UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton
```

which pushes a new controller to allow editing it or delete.

**EDITED:**

There is a TableView Delegate to detect when the accessory was tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would they select a row

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand your question :) - But if you add an UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton, there is a delegate on the TableView called: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: At the moment, you tap on a row and tap select. Which selects the row. If I have a disclosure button, this will not allow for selection of the row.

Comment: By tapping the accessory you get the index that was tapped. This index should correspond to the NSArray or NSMutableArray with populates the table. It is also the same index as if the row was tapped. If you have the index of the NSArray or NSMutableArray, you can obtain a reference to the object.

Comment: The problem isn't detecting the selection, but that at the moment when the user taps on a row it does nothing, except highlight the cell. They can then click select on the navigation bar. If I add a disclosure button to allow renaming, I won't be able to allow selection of a row.

Comment: Selecting the Accessory and Selecting the Row are 2 different events. It should work...

Answer (score 0):

Do absolutely the same you'd do for any other tableView in your app.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    //delete rows etc.
  }
}
```

Regarding renaming, think this through again, noone actually needs to rename the rows in search results. They're being taken from original data source, which isn't getting changed, so what's the point in renaming them anyway?

Comment: Thanks, So your saying have a maintenance screen in settings perhaps? I was thinking, in the mail app when you click edit it brings up some options at the bottom, but I dunno how this would work for rename as you can select multiple rows.